# How do I initialize a const std::pair?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

Let's say that I've got a :

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> my_pair;
```

how do I initialize a const my_pair ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use its constructor:

```
const my_pair p( 1, 2 );
```

Answer (score 28):

With C++11 you can also use one of the following:

```
const my_pair p = {2, 3};
const my_pair p({2, 3});
const my_pair p{2, 3};
```

Answer (score 19):

```
const my_pair p = std::make_pair( 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

const my_pair p = my_pair(3, 2);